# VBA how to copy a row subset from a sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy for each not empty row in first sheet (wsIn), a subset row of it in second sheet (wsGruppo)

my subset copy source starts from column E up to the last not empty column (at right) ....each row is processed inside a while loop (rowOut index)

my paste column in second sheet is column H at row x (x has its own increment)

I did this stuff but it loops:

```
Range("E" & rowOut).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
wsGruppo.Select
wsGruppo.Cells.Range("H" & rowOut2).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. `copy for each not empty row` then you proceed to write `a subset row of it`. What does subset mean? The row immediately below? How do you determine where the "subset" starts?

Comment: simply a subset row is made by n column where n<number of column for each row, maybe what I wrote describe better: "my subset copy source starts from column E up to the last not empty column"